# Regular Expression - Extracting all the contents from an email sent or replied by the same person in a email chain

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a set of chain email sent between 3 people. I am trying to find a way to extract all emails that were either sent or replied by one of the people. Is there a way we could do this using regular expressions?

I am trying to do this in Python

Given below is how the email goes:

```
From: Riefel, Paul [mailto:paul@mail.com]
Sent: Tuesday, September 18, 2018 10:28 AM
To: Waugh, Steve <steve.w@mail.com>, Scott, P <scott.p@abc.com>
Subject: RE: [Sales] Report 

Ok Noted.

_____________________________

From: Scott, P <scott.p@abc.com>
Sent: Tuesday, September 18, 2018 11:28 AM
To: Waugh, Steve <steve.w@mail.com>, Riefel, Paul [mailto:paul@mail.com]
Subject: RE: [Sales] Report 

Hi,

This is a sample weekly sales report.
```

Assuming this chain goes on for few more exchanges, is there a way we can extract all the text sent or replied by a specific email address (for example `paul@mail.com` in this case).

Comment: what language are you coding with??

Comment: Interesting question, but it's missing a lot of information and needs a [mcve]. Are you guaranteed an underscore separator between emails, or are you using the `From:`/`Sent:` header as the separator? Please provide a full input and output example along with your regex attempt.

Comment: @Tobey, planning to use Python for this.

Answer (score 1):

As for the content of the email, this regex below,

`(?s)(?<=\bSubject\b.)([^_]*$)`

grabs all of the text after "Subject:" to the first underscore character we encounter.

> RE: [Sales] Report
>
> Ok Noted.

&

> RE: [Sales] Report
>
> Hi,
>
> This is a sample weekly sales report.

[Generate code for python](https://regex101.com/r/PpMkAm/1)

Then search for senders,

`(?<=\bFrom\b.).+`

This could be more refined but there seems to be little pattern in the email chain senders, so this will have to do for now.

> Riefel, Paul [mailto:paul@mail.com]

&

> Scott, P [scott.p@abc.com]

[Generate Code for python](https://regex101.com/r/lB7GRz/1)

Both regex searches should be indexed the same, meaning you can combine these two lists (sender, content) and then filter/manipulate as you please.

Regex Tested using regex.101.com